# Can anyone recommend any good literature about Honeypots?

Tags: untagged

I'm interested in learning more about Honeypots and Honeynets. I've used low interaction Honeypots like Honeyd in the past, but now I want to take it to the next level.

Can anyone recommend any good books or papers about Honeypots/Honeynets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a [few books](http://www.honeypots.net/honeypots/books) on the subject (although I've never bothered with them), however I can recommend you some readily updated websites:

[The always interesting honeyblog](http://honeyblog.org/)

[The European Network of Affined Honeypots has many recent papers and presentations](http://www.fp6-noah.org/publications/)

[The Honeynet Project has some good papers](http://www.honeynet.org/papers)

[Distributed honeypot management software](http://microsolved.com/?page_id=69) and [a video discussion of the current state of the threat](http://microsolved.com/?page_id=219)

[A directory of honeypot server related sites](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Security/Honeypots_and_Honeynets//)

[Shadowserver has some good general stats](http://www.shadowserver.org/wiki/pmwiki.php/Information/Honeypots)

Finally there are some old (circa 2000) papers cited in [this article](http://www.sans.org/resources/idfaq/honeypot3.php)

Answer (score 1):

I just finished reading the book [Beautiful Security](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596527489), and it has a nice chapter on 'honey clients'.  Instead of focusing on server side exploits, they look at how malware installs itself onto a client.  The book has some good suggestions on using VMWare, and detecting system changes.

[Beautiful Security http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51wsK04PePL._SL160_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51wsK04PePL._SL160_.jpg)